# How to determine if an Android device has a screen i.e. whether it is an Android set top box?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I know one can obtain screen sizes, but I would like to know if someone has ever been able to find out if the Android device has a screen or not. i.e. whether it is a set top box or not.

I guess screen size returned should be "zero", but I am not sure if that is actually the response in the real world.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [check for a TV device](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html#runtime-check).

```
public static final String TAG = "DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck";

UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because it checks the UI layout which is the same for Android STBs and Android TVs